# ArgoCD deployment to eks and aks

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-eks, argocd

Is there any way that ArgoCD deploy to AKS and EKS cluster simultaneously. I don't see anything setting in ArgoCD to connect to another cluster. My aim is that I want ArgoCD to deploy in both AKS and EKS. As of now since ArgoCD is deployed to EKS so by default its picking it up but I want to connect ArgoCD with AKS as well. If there is a way please tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can deploy to multiple clusters or external clusters using the Argo CD.

please check this out : https://blog.doit-intl.com/automating-kubernetes-multi-cluster-config-with-argo-cd-5ac5e371ef01

if your argo CD is running local on same host

you can check the existing clusters using the

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

and using cluster context **Name** you can add the context to the Argo CD via **agro cli**

```
argocd cluster add RESPECTIVE-CONTEXT name
```

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/commands/argocd_cluster_add/

readmore at : https://itnext.io/argocd-setup-external-clusters-by-name-d3d58a53acb0

Comment: How would I connect to AKS cluster if the ArgoCD is deployed to EKS?

Comment: for that same only shared all necessary document you have to read : https://itnext.io/argocd-setup-external-clusters-by-name-d3d58a53acb0#:~:text=Adding%20an%20external%20cluster%20to%20ArgoCD&text=yaml.,a%20guestbook%20namespace%20in%20it.

Comment: you can save the cluster details in `Kind:cluster` and save the external cluster or another cluster on argoCD. by this way you can also deploy on multiple cluster while running argoCD on single place.

Comment: from UI side also maybe you can add the cluster using `/settings/clusters` if you read the documentation.